# How to convert timestemp to readable values? [Pandas Dataframe]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Here is an dataframe I'm working with:

```
     date           price   trade size                                             
     1417412036    300.0    0.010000                                 
     1417412423    300.0    0.010000                       
     1417415048    370.0    0.010000                                         
     1417416612    370.0    0.026556                                               
     1417498166    377.0    0.010000
```

How do I convert the values of index to human readable dates?

For example 
1420705427 should change to 2015-01-08T03:23:47

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way is to use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) specifying the unit:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='s')
```

You can also use `transform` if you want, but will be slower

```
import datetime
df.date.transform(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

Both methods yield the same output:

```
0   2014-12-01 05:33:56
1   2014-12-01 05:40:23
2   2014-12-01 06:24:08
3   2014-12-01 06:50:12
4   2014-12-02 05:29:26
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are actually [epoch times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

You could do what RafaelC is doing. An alternative is to do

```
In [8]: import time

In [9]: time.localtime(1417412036)
Out[9]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=21, tm_min=33, tm_sec=56, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=334, tm_isdst=0)

In [10]: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1417412036))
Out[10]: '2014-11-30 21:33:56'
```

IS this the kind of readable time you want?